# Error in ValidationRule method after updating ReactiveUI.Validation up to 2.1.1 version

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, reactiveui

I updated my ReactiveUI.Validation package from version 1.5 and now it's `<package id="ReactiveUI.Validation" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net472" />`. But after this I encountered the following:

1. I needed to replace all generic `ReactiveValidationObject<InputParamViewModel>` with `ReactiveValidationObject`. Overwise, it's underlined like error. OK, fine. I did it.
2. And all the next errors are related to ValidationRule methods and if in the previous version this :

```
    var intervalIsValid = this
                    .WhenAnyValue(x => x.From.Value, x => x.To.Value, x => x.ForceValidation,
                        (from, to, forceValidation) => new Interval<decimal?> {From = From.Value, To = To.Value}).Select(x =>
                    (!ForceValidation && (x.From == null && x.To == null)) || x.IntervalIsValid(IsMandatory));

this.ValidationRule(_ => intervalIsValid, (vm, state) => !state ? Validation.IncorrectValue : string.Empty);
```

works perfectly, in the new version it's unacceptable due to the wrong params in ValidationRule method (Cannot resolve method ValidationRule(lambda expression, lambda expression)).

3. I tried to replace that ValidationRule with this:

```
var observableValue = this
                .WhenAnyValue(x => x.From.Value, x => x.To.Value, x => x.ForceValidation,
                    (from, to, forceValidation) => new Interval<decimal?> { From = From.Value, To = To.Value });

this.ValidationRule(observableValue, x => (!ForceValidation && (x.From == null && x.To == null)) || (x.IntervalIsValid(IsMandatory)), state => Validation.IncorrectValue);
```

according to documentation (https://www.reactiveui.net/api/reactiveui.validation.extensions/validatableviewmodelextensions/83edc663).

Now there are no errors and the app compiles but this validation doesn't work. The fields are accepted all the time even though I leave them empty. I receive no error message from my app and it continues working.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `ReactiveValidationObject`, then I'd suppose that [ReactiveUI.Validation](http://github.com/reactiveui/reactiveui.validation) integrates with the UI framework that relies on the [`INotifyDataErrorInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo?view=net-5.0) implementation, and no `BindValidation` extension method is involved. In this case, according to the [ReactiveValidationObject](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Validation/blob/d5089c933e046c5ee4a13149491593045cda161a/src/ReactiveUI.Validation/Helpers/ReactiveValidationObject.cs#L86-L94) implementation, providing the names for the validated properties might help. Let's consider the following code snippet as an example:

```cs
IObservable<bool> passwordsObservable =
    this.WhenAnyValue(
        x => x.Password,
        x => x.ConfirmPassword,
        (password, confirmation) => password == confirmation);

this.ValidationRule(
    vm => vm.ConfirmPassword, // The property name selector expression.
    passwordsObservable,      // IObservable<bool>
    "Passwords must match."); // Validation error text.
```

The code snippet above tells ReactiveUI.Validation that a new validation rule should be created from an object of type `IObservable<bool>` that indicates the validity of a property, and the associated property name is determined based on the provided selector expression (e.g. from `vm => vm.ConfirmPassword` we get the `ConfirmPassword` property name).

If that validation rule wasn't associated with a property (e.g. if we didn't pass a property name), then the library wouldn't be able to figure out which validation rules are associated with a validated property. So a rule of thumb when working with `INotifyDataErrorInfo` and regular WPF or Avalonia bindings is to always specify the property name.

If the issue persists or you get stuck in resolving this, feel free to file a new issue in the [ReactiveUI.Validation repository](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Validation) with a repro project, this way we'll be able to look through the codebase and help out with fixing this!

Worth noting, that we have evergreen sample apps targeting Avalonia, WPF, Xamarin Forms etc. in the ReactiveUI.Validation core repository https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Validation/blob/d5089c933e046c5ee4a13149491593045cda161a/samples/LoginApp/ViewModels/SignUpViewModel.cs#L43 So if you'd like to familiarize yourself with the updated `ValidationRule` APIs, feel free to browse and debug the `LoginApp.*.sln` sample solutions (`LoginApp.Wpf.sln` should be relevant according to the hashtags).

[image: ReactiveUI.Validation demo]